# Doing a knockout foreach on an observable's sub property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is my div.

```
<div id="storyBody" data-bind="foreach: CurrentStory.Paragraphs">
    <p data-bind="text: $data">

    </p>
</div>
```

Here is my model:

```
$(function ()
{
    var currentUser = "";

    nm.Story = function()
    {

        this.Paragraphs = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.CurrentEditorId = ko.observable();
        this.LastEditorId = ko.observable();


    };

    nm.StoryPreview = function()
    {

        this.Preview = "";
        this.documentId = 0;


    };

    nm.vm = function ()
    {

        var UserStoryList = ko.observableArray([]),
            CurrentStory = ko.observable(),
            GetCurrentStory = function (data) {
                nm.getStory(data.documentId, GetCurrentStoryCallback, GetCurrentStoryErrorCallback)
            },
            GetCurrentStoryCallback = function (data) {
                var story = new nm.Story().CurrentEditorId(data.CurrentEditorId)
                     .LastEditorId(data.LastEditorId);
                     story.Paragraphs(data.Paragraphs);

                CurrentStory(story);
            },
            GetCurrentStoryErrorCallback = function (data) {

            },
            LoadUserStoriesList = function() {

                nm.getStories(LoadUserStoriesListCallback, LoadUserStoriesListErrorCallback);

            },
            LoadUserStoriesListCallback = function(data)
            {

                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    var storyPreview = new nm.StoryPreview();
                    storyPreview.Preview = value.Preview;
                    storyPreview.documentId = value.DocumentId;
                    UserStoryList.push(storyPreview);
                });


            },
            LoadUserStoriesListErrorCallback = function (data)
            {



            };

        return {

            UserStoryList: UserStoryList,
            CurrentStory: CurrentStory,
            LoadUserStoriesList : LoadUserStoriesList,
            LoadUserStoriesListCallback: LoadUserStoriesListCallback,
            GetCurrentStory: GetCurrentStory

        }

    }();


    nm.vm.LoadUserStoriesList();
    ko.applyBindings(nm.vm);

});
```

Seems like this should work, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: The work around that works is to put the paragraphs on the root of my model, but I wanted to model to retain this structure, cuz I'm anal. I can also get it to work if I nest a span inside the div using "with". But I wanted to know that this definitely won't work or not.

Comment: What is your question ? Can you make a fiddle that focus on your problem ?

Comment: The binding doesn't work once the CurrentStory is set. There's no error in the console, just nothing appears in the DOM. I'll try an whip up a little fiddle with just the necessary components.

Comment: This html works:     <div id="storyBody" data-bind="with: CurrentStory">
        <span data-bind="foreach: Paragraphs">
        <p data-bind="text: $data">
            
        </p>
        </span>
    </div>

Comment: But I'd rather use the other version

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some parenthesis.

Could you try with:

```
<div id="storyBody" data-bind="foreach: CurrentStory().Paragraphs">
    <p data-bind="text: $data">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That only works with a "with" and then it only dumps all the paragrpahs into a single <p> tag.